# contracts-ui cannot connect to local node

Tags: substrate-contracts-node, contracts

When following ink getting started tutorial at https://use.ink/getting-started/running-substrate I am stuck at one of the steps.

After starting contracts node in dev mode with the following command:

```sh
substrate-contracts-node --dev
```

I am trying to connect to UI via https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ choosing local node. Getting

```
Could not connect to ws://127.0.0.1:9944
Make sure you are running a local substrate-contracts-node.
substrate-contracts-node --dev
```

I tried switching off `ufw` but it didn't help.

I found similar question here but there problem was missing `--dev` switch, which is not the case here, I pass `--dev` explicitly.

This is the output of my node console

```
2023-11-13 09:46:10.415  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Substrate Contracts Node    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.33.0-unknown    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2021-2023    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Development    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: cool-jellyfish-4492    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-11-13 09:46:10.416  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: ParityDb at /tmp/substrateeTNwIZ/chains/dev/paritydb/full    
2023-11-13 09:46:11.566  WARN main sub-libp2p: Can't listen on /ip6/::/tcp/30333 because: Other(Custom { kind: Other, error: Custom { kind: Other, error: Other(Left(Left(Left(Left(Right(Transport(Os { code: 97, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Address family not supported by protocol" }))))))) } })    
2023-11-13 09:46:12.660  INFO main sc_rpc_server: Running JSON-RPC server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]
```

How the debug why it is not running as it should?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I think some of them blocks access to not secure websockets `ws://`. You should allow that in the browser's config.

Comment: I am using Brave, tried on Firefox now and it does work! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers do not allow access/connection to not secure websocket (`ws://`) so you need to allow that by changing your browser's configs.

(OP and I use firefox and it works without changes)